# Sqlite compare with current date only

Tags: android, sqlite

I am storing the date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`. I compare this with the current date. The query is like so:

```
public Cursor getData() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();        
    String queryGetData = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
              + " WHERE " + SEARCH_DATE + " >=  date('now') LIMIT 5";
    Cursor result = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queryGetData, null);
    return  result;
}
```

The problem with this is that the query does not return any results if they were created at an earlier time (but still on the same day). Again I am only saving the date part in the database not the time.

What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Can you update the question with the table structure, and actual data. My guess is that you are not actually storing the data as yyyy-MM-dd but in some other format, otherwise the time would not be a factor. You could also try `String queryGetData = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
              + " WHERE date(" + SEARCH_DATE + ") >=  date('now') LIMIT 5";`

Comment: @MikeT I tried your query and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not actually storing the data as yyyy-MM-dd but in some other format that includes the time, otherwise the time would not be a factor.

You could try :-

```
    String queryGetData = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE date(" + SEARCH_DATE + ") >= date('now') LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your datetime format is not wrong, you can check and add the **localtime** parameter to the **date**() function

```
String queryGetData = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME 
              + " WHERE " + SEARCH_DATE + " >=  date('now', 'localtime') LIMIT 5";
```

**Attention**:

- when using the Date function, notice the **localtime** param in **date()**